# ¿Como CONTAR objetos repetidos de un array en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

```
let paises= [{
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 30
  },
  {
    id_pais: 3,
    nombre: 'Brasil',
    codigo_localidad: 20
  },
  {
    id_pais: 4,
    nombre: 'Francia',
    codigo_localidad: 30
  },
  {
    id_pais: 5,
    nombre: 'Japón',
    codigo_localidad: 70
  },
  {
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 30
  }
];
```

Como se puede observar hay un **id** dentro de los objetos que está repetido (**"id_producto": 2**), mi pregunta es ¿Cómo se puede **CONTAR** ese objeto para que '**codigo_localidad**' se modifique a **2** ya que son dos veces la que se repite. Gracias!

Debería de quedar así:

```
[{
        id_pais: 2,
        nombre: 'Argentina',
        codigo_localidad: 2
      },
      {
        id_pais: 3,
        nombre: 'Brasil',
        codigo_localidad: 20
      },
      {
        id_pais: 4,
        nombre: 'Francia',
        codigo_localidad: 30
      },
      {
        id_pais: 5,
        nombre: 'Japón',
        codigo_localidad: 70
      }
];
```

Donde 'codigo_localidad' en 'Argentina' es = 2. CUENTA las veces que se repite y se coloca en este caso en 'codigo_localidad' esas veces que se repitieron.

Comment: No entiendo, codigo de localidad de cada elemento debe ser igual a la cantidad de elementos repetidos?

Comment: El codigo_localidad del elemento repetido solamente debería de ser igual a la cantidad de elemntos repetidos, en este caso 'Argentina' debería de tener codigo_localidad = 2, y que devuelva 1 sólo objeto en conjunto con los otros que no estaban repetidos.

Comment: Hola @MarianoFaridHayward, gracias por tu pregunta. Para entender mejor tu pregunta, lo que deseas es retornar el array sin el o los objetos que tengan cualquier valor repetido en el Array.? O bien, contar cuantos objetos tienen valores repetidos en el array. O bien, que tengan id_pais repetido?. O bien, lo que deseas es el objeto que tenga un valor repetido, removerlo y al codigo_localidad agregar la cantidad de veces que ese pais se repite?. Podrias por favor darme contexto, asi poder darte algunas opciones.

Comment: Ejemplo: SI Argentina se repitiera 4 veces, entonces se elminan esos tres repetidos y al codigo_localidad del pais con repeticiones tendria como valor 4. Asi seria la logica?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola @boykland, gracias por tu tiempo. Ahí modifiqué el contenido para que se entienda pero sería que me retorne el objeto repetido (1 sola vez) y en codigo_localidad se coloque = 2, ya que fueron 2 veces las que se repitieron. A parte de retornar los otros objetos que no estaban repetidos. Quedarían TODOS los objetos sin repetir + el que estaba repetido (1 sola vez) con codigo_localidad = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque no simplemente creamos otro arreglo que guarde los objeto de acuerdo al `id` y usan la función `forEarch` para ello:

```JavaScript
let repeated={};
paises.forEach(function(e,i) {
    let id = e["id_pais"];
    if (repeated[id] == undefined) {
        repeated[id] = [e];//Obtenemos el objeto.
    } else {
        repeated[id].push(e);//Insertamos otro objeto si se repite el indice repetido.
    }
});
```

Ahora que tenemos los objetos repetidos en un array[] vemos si hay más elementos repetidos en ese array, en ese caso le ingresamos la cantidad de objetos repetidos.

```JavaScript
let output=[];
for(let i in repeated){//recorremos todos los índices de los objetos repetidos.
    output.push(repeated[i][0]);
    if (repeated[i].length>1)//Hay mas de un objeto repetido.
        output[output.length-1]["codigo_localidad"]=repeated[i].length;//Como se repite le colocamos la cantidad de repetidos.
}
```

El código total quedaría así:

```js
let paises = [{
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 30
  },
  {
    id_pais: 3,
    nombre: 'Brasil',
    codigo_localidad: 20
  },
  {
    id_pais: 4,
    nombre: 'Francia',
    codigo_localidad: 30
  },
  {
    id_pais: 5,
    nombre: 'Japón',
    codigo_localidad: 70
  },
  {
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 30
  }
];
function get_arr_not_repeated(arr){
    let repeated = {};
    arr.forEach(function(e,i) {
        let id = e["id_pais"];
        if (repeated[id] == undefined) {
            repeated[id] = [e];//Obtenemos el objeto.
        } else {
            repeated[id].push(e);//Insertamos otro objeto si se repite el indice repetido.
        }
    });
    let output=[];
    for(let i in repeated){//recorremos todos los indices de los objetos repetidos.
        output.push(repeated[i][0]);
        if (repeated[i].length>1)//Hay mas de un objeto repetido.
            output[output.length-1]["codigo_localidad"]=repeated[i].length;//Como se repite le colocamos la cantidad de repetidos.
    }
    return output;
}
var not_repeated=get_arr_not_repeated(paises);
console.log(not_repeated);
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que necesito que quede de esta manera:
[{
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 2
  },
  {
    id_pais: 3,
    nombre: 'Brasil',
    codigo_localidad: 20
  },
  {
    id_pais: 4,
    nombre: 'Francia',
    codigo_localidad: 30
  },
  {
    id_pais: 5,
    nombre: 'Japón',
    codigo_localidad: 70
  }
];
Es decir, en el caso del país "Argentina" se repitió 2 veces, quiero que me devuelva una sola vez y en la propiedad cod_localidad = 2 (porque fueron 2 veces las que se repitió). Quedaría como muestro arriba

Comment: ok, editare la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Gacias por tu pregunta.

Aca tienes otra opción.

```js
const paises = [
  {
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 30,
  },
  {
    id_pais: 3,
    nombre: 'Brasil',
    codigo_localidad: 20,
  },
  {
    id_pais: 4,
    nombre: 'Francia',
    codigo_localidad: 30,
  },
  {
    id_pais: 4,
    nombre: 'Francia',
    codigo_localidad: 30,
  },
  {
    id_pais: 5,
    nombre: 'Japón',
    codigo_localidad: 70,
  },
  {
    id_pais: 3,
    nombre: 'Brasil',
    codigo_localidad: 20,
  },
  {
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 30,
  },
  {
    id_pais: 2,
    nombre: 'Argentina',
    codigo_localidad: 30,
  },
];

let arrCountriesNonDupli = [];
let arrCountriesIdCounted = [];

paises.forEach((countryA, indxA, arrCountries) => {
  // validar si el pais ya fue contado en la busqueda de duplicados
  const isCountryCounted = arrCountriesIdCounted.includes(countryA.id_pais);
  // Si no ha sido contado
  if (!isCountryCounted) {
    arrCountriesIdCounted.push(countryA.id_pais);

    // Buscar cuantas coincidencias existen del pais en el array
    const countriesToCount = arrCountries.filter(
      (ele) => ele.id_pais === countryA.id_pais
    );

    const country =
      /* Si hay mas de dos coincidencias en la busqueda, entonces 
contar cuantas hubo, modificar el codigo_local con el valor del contador, y agregar el pais al array*/
      countriesToCount.length > 1
        ? {
            ...countryA,
            codigo_localidad: countriesToCount.length,
          }
       /* Si solo hay una concidencia en la busqueda, agregar el pais tal cual esta.*/
        : countryA;

    arrCountriesNonDupli.push(country);
  }
});

console.log('arrCountriesNonDuplicated', arrCountriesNonDupli);
```

## Recomendaciones

***Estas son algunas consideraciones que puedes seguir basados en las buenas prácticas en el ciclo de vida de un código del lado del frontend y otras en general para el contexto de Javascript***

1. Utilizar declariaciones de variables, funciones, clases, archivos, etc.. con nombres en el idioma global, por el momento el ***Inglés***. Esto trae beneficios considerables como: Cualquier persona del mundo te puede ayudar, estandarizar tu código, puedes evitar problemas de internacionalizacion en tu código, el mantenimiento se vuelve mas facil y eficiente porque todos entenderan el mismo idioma.
2. La delaración de las propiedades de un **Objeto Javascript** o un **Objeto JSON**, declararlas o nombrarlas con ***LowerCamelCase***, es decir si tienes ***id_pais*** podría ser ***idPais***, implementando la recomendacion uno, se vería como ***countryId***. De esta forma puedes evitar problemas de mapeo, casting, acceso a los datos, temas de formato, legilibilidad en tu código, entre otros beneficios
3. En javascript es importante definir el ***ámbito de la variable*** o ***variable scope***; Es decir el uso de **var**, **let**, **const**. De esta forma el compilador le dira a la memoria si crecera o no el valor de la variable. En tu código declarastes paises con el ambito ***let*** `let paises = .....`, el valor de esta variable no cambiará, entonces debería ser una constante `const paises = ...`
4. Antes que immplementes cualquier propuesta o idea que sale de una respuesta  en stackoverflow, es importante que hagas tus propios benchmark de test, es decir probar, testear el codigo propuesto, validar que cumplan con los principios de un código (Legible, mantenible, rendimiento, seguro, etc..). Asi te evitas inconvenientes al momento de liberar tu codigo a otros ambientes o a produccion.

Gracias por tu tiempo al leer mi propuesta

Saludes